# Authentication required message when sending email

Tags: php, sendgrid, laravel-5.8

I am trying send email verification links to user when they register but I get  a message `Authentication required` and mail isn't sent. I tried using mailtrap for demo and sendgrid which I will be using in production but the message was the same. This is how I a going about it

After running `composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle` I updated my env file like this

```
# MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
# MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
# MAIL_PORT=2525
# MAIL_USERNAME=mailtrap_username
# MAIL_PASSWORD=mailtrap_password
# MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.sendgrid.net
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=sendgrid_username
MAIL_PASSWORD=sendgrid_password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

In the controller, I want to send the mail after a user is successfully created like this

```
...
use App\Mail\VerifyEmail;

...
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

public function register(Request $request)
{
    // create and store new user record
    $user = User::create([
        'username'  => $request->username,
        'password'  => bcrypt($request->password)
    ]);

    // send user email verification link
    Mail::to($user->username)->send(new VerifyEmail());
}
```

VerifyMail.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class VerifyEmail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        $from = 'support@fromus.com';
        $name = 'custom name';
        $subject = 'Welcome! Confirm Your Email';

        return $this->from($from, $name)
            ->subject($subject)
            ->view('auth.verify');
    }
}
```

Following the documentation for email verification https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/verification#verification-routing I added the `Auth::routes(['verify' => true])` to `api.php` file like this

```
<?php

// Register routes for email verification
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);

Route::prefix('v1')->group(function () {

    // protected routes
    Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function () {

        Route::get('products', 'ProductController@index'); // get products

    });

});

Route::fallback(function () {
    return response()->json(['error' => 'Not Found'], 404);
});
```

Why am I getting the `Authentication required` error message and how can I fix it?

Comment: have you tried restarting laravel and also run `composer updated, php artisan config:cache` ?

Comment: @ViperTecPro I did not have to restart laravel. First I removed `Auth::routes(['verify' => true])` from `api.php` and added it to 'web.php` then ran `php artisan config:cache`. That fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First i removed `Auth::routes(['verify' => true])` from the `api.php` file and added it in the `web.php`.
Then I ran `php artisan config:cache` to cache changes made to the `env` file. Fixed